# Access denied on CreateFile in user folder

Tags: security, token, createfile

From one application running with USER1 account, I want to access a file that is located under C:\Users\ADMIN

USER1 is limited and ADMIN is an administrator account.

The process has an admin token obtained from LogonUser api and tried with ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and SetThreadToken (using DuplicateToken/SecurityImpersonation) but in both cases I obtain a ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL error when I call CreateFile.

I'm almost sure I have to deal with a security issue but no idea how to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that target process needs to have `SeImpersonateUser` privilege, available only in `SYSTEM` processes by default.

When the thread is impersonated, because the process hasn't the required privilege, the api will succeed but actual level will be **Delegate** instead of **Impersonate** and `CreateFile` fails because of this.